# Use android tab display with raspberry pi

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi

I want to use my old android tab(dead) display with Raspberry pi.I am thinking of connecting screen via i/o ports of Raspberry pi. So I need to find display driver for tabs screen, as my Tab is dead, I can not find its display specification & can not find manufacturer, Is there any other way so that I can move further? Can extracting display driver from tab android os help?

Comment: I am not sure if this question belongs here. It is not directly connected to programming. You might be able to get help on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ByteHamster I am not sure there too, read my last line in question